# Get LabelNames of Bars on a BarChart - ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

How can I get the `labelname` of the bar when I click on it, and set to a variable on `.cs` file? I'm using `ASP.NET` with `C#`

The chart:

[image]

```
<dx:WebChartControl ID="WebChartControl1" runat="server"  CrosshairEnabled="True" DataSourceID="Tablita" Height="337px" Width="773px" PaletteName="Concourse" OnCustomCallback="WebChartControl1_CustomCallback" OnCustomDrawSeriesPoint="WebChartControl1_CustomDrawSeriesPoint">
    <DiagramSerializable>
        <dx:XYDiagram>
            <AxisX VisibleInPanesSerializable="-1" Title-Text="category" LabelVisibilityMode="AutoGeneratedAndCustom">
                <Label Angle="90">
                </Label>
            </AxisX>
            <AxisY VisibleInPanesSerializable="-1" Title-Text="Qty" Title-Visibility="Default">
                <Tickmarks MinorVisible="False" />
                <Label TextPattern="{V:$#,#}">
                </Label>
                <VisualRange Auto="False" MaxValueSerializable="10000" MinValueSerializable="1" />
                <WholeRange Auto="False" MaxValueSerializable="10000" MinValueSerializable="1" />
            </AxisY>
        </dx:XYDiagram>
    </DiagramSerializable>
```

And I want to pass to other `Webform` to set on `loadpage` like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string var;
    var = LabelName.Text;
}
```

If its necessary to use `Javascript`, please tell me.

Comment: Noe this is not native asp.net webforms, more like a 3rd party control. Perhaps DevEx?

Comment: Actually I'm using DevExpress